# Maven compilation jibx plugin

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, jibx

I recently upgraded java from 1.6 to 1.8 in my maven project.
I'm using Eclipse IDE, and since that upgrade my pom.xml does not compile anymore because an error is shown on the jibx plugin :
*Should never be called with null root (org.jibx:jibx-maven-plugin:1.3.1:bind:default:process-classes)*
Here is my jibx plugin declaration in pom.xml, I tryed different things but I cannot resolve this error:

```
               <!-- JIBX -->
                <plugin> 
                    <groupId>org.jibx</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jibx-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>1.3.1</version>
                    <configuration> 
                        <validate>false</validate>
                        <schemaBindingDirectory>src/main/resources/oxm/bindings</schemaBindingDirectory>
                        <includeSchemaBindings>
                            <includeSchemaBinding>xxx.xml</includeSchemaBinding>
                            <includeSchemaBinding>xxx.xml</includeSchemaBinding> 
                            <includeSchemaBinding>xxx.xml</includeSchemaBinding>
                            <includeSchemaBinding>xxx.xml</includeSchemaBinding>
                        </includeSchemaBindings>
                        <load>true</load>
                        <validate>false</validate>
                        <verify>false</verify>
                        <verbose>false</verbose>
                    </configuration>
                    <dependencies>
                        <dependency>
                            <groupId>org.jibx</groupId>
                            <artifactId>jibx-bind</artifactId>
                            <version>1.3.1</version> 
                        </dependency>
                    </dependencies>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <phase>process-classes</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>bind</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>   
...
<dependencies>
...
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jibx</groupId>
            <artifactId>jibx-run</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.1</version>
            <exclusions><!-- xpp excluded because in conflict with another version provided in websphere -->
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>xpp3</artifactId>
                    <groupId>xpp3</groupId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
...
<dependencies>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally got my solution : comment `<validate>false</validate>` or set it to `true`